# How to Loop inside Pentaho Data Integration Transformation

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have following pdi job structure:

```
START ---> TR1 ---> TR2 ---> TR3
```

where:

`TR1` will return 3 rows,

`TR2` had `execute every input row` enabled by me, and will return 5 rows,

`TR3` had `execute every input row` enabled by me, and it was **supposedly** run 15 times (5 times for each of those 3 `TR2`).

My expectation was:

`TR1` will run exactly 1 time, `TR2` will run exactly 3 times in parallel (since `TR1` returning 3 rows),

and `TR3` will run exactly 15 times (since each of `TR2` returning 5 rows).

But then **the reality was**

`TR2` was executed 3 times, **as expected**,

but `TR3` is only executed 1 time, **not as expected.**

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How to make `TR3` act as like loop inside `TR2`'s rows

Comment: Try creating one more job.
1st job will have TR1 and TR2 and 2nd job will have 1st job and TR3, try this out.

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to create job try this sequence

Start-tr1-(job1(tr2-subjob2(tr3)))-End

**job1 and job2 will be checked with execute every input raw.**

Dis-
create job1 and connect to tr1 and put tr2 inside it after that create subjob2 and connect to tr2 after that put tr3 inside subjob2

Comment: @xcode, this answer will fit you better becuase you will have a better control over variables and executions than with 3 straight up TR calls in 1 job,

Answer (score 0):

I assume, TR represents transformation and all the TR's are part of a job? if that's the case, then all you need to do is - in TR1 send the results to TR2 by connecting the last step in TR1 with "Copy rows to result", upon which double click on the TR2 with in the job and go to "Advanced" and check "Copy previous results to parameters" and "execute to every input row".

Now, within that add the column names from TR1 under the parameters tab of TR2 in the same sequence with same names. And then within the TR2 properties add those as parameters with a null default value so that you can use the values generated from the previous transformation as variables in TR2. And now include TR3 within the TR2 so that it even executes for each row generated by TR1. I hope I didn't confuse. Let me know if doesn't make sense.